# What exactly do ducks do?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In the new End of the Line update, TF2 has a Duck Journal available to buy, as well as a Duck Token, which increases the level of the Duck journal, claiming to increase the number of ducks dropped.

But what do ducks do? Are they a cosmetic item (I can't seem to find any in my inventory), and can I see how many ducks I've collected?

Comment: Well if it _looks_ like a duck and it _sounds_ like a duck...

Comment: @Alex So since this is TF2, you should probably hit people over the head with it like a fish.  Or wear it as a hat.

Comment: As someone who doesn't play Tf2. What the hell is this game smoking.

Comment: @Rapitor There's a lot of humor in TF2.  You **are** talking about an FPS that added a set of bumpercar minigames on Halloween after all.  And has a taunt where people do a conga. Heck, this update added a new melee weapon that is a US railroad crossing sign.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Killing other players will cause them to drop ducks.  The higher the Duck Journal level, the more ducks drop when a player kills someone.  Duck Journal Levels *also* cost $5 each in the Mann Co. Store (the Duck Token you already mentioned).

Journal owners can grab ducks to count towards your current Duck Streak (or start one if they don't have a duck streak going).

If you don't have a Duck Journal, they do nothing except make noises when you collect them.  Usually, they make quacking noises, but the glittering ones will cause one of the Merasmus "Bonus Ducks" lines to play.

### Duck Streaks

Duck Streaks are like a parody of Killstreaks.  Like Killstreaks, messages will display on screen when a player passes certain numbers of ducks.

Duck Streaks reset upon death.

The duck journal is also an Action slot item.  The higher your Duck Streak the louder it quacks when you hit the Action button.

This event goes away on January 5th... but since Valve added it as a Holiday to the game code, plugins (like the [one I wrote](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=1587251)) may be able to enable it again after it ends.

Comment: Life is like a hurricane...

Comment: @Zibbobz ...here in, Duckberg.

Comment: wtf, did I seriously misspell Duckburg in that post?